# Does FluentMigrator work with SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, fluent-migrator

Does Fluent Migrator not support SQL Server 2014? 
I am getting below exception - 
“The major version of the database server could not be determined or is not supported by FluentMigrator.”

Answer (score 2):

**Update: As of 2014-12-31 Fluent Migrator *does* support SQL Server 2014.**

No, As of today (15.Dec.2014) Fluent Migrator doesn't support SQL Server 2014 version.
You can verify it in below wiki page.
https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Supported-Databases

Answer (score 1):

Both yes and no. There is no explicit support yet but for 90% of features, it is the same code for Sql Server 2005, 2008, 2012 and 2014. If you specify the provider (see [Command Line options here](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Command-Line-Runner-Options)) as Sql Server 2012 then your migrations should work.

```
migrate --configPath "WithConnectionString.config" -conn "Test.Connection" --provider sqlserver2012 --assembly ".\Migrations\bin\Debug\Migrations.dll"
```

New features in Sql Server 2014 will not be supported but at this stage every new release of Sql Server contains few new features that affect FluentMigrator. For example, the only new features that Sql Server 2012 introduced and that affected FluentMigrator were [sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) and clustered indexes. Here is the [Pull Request for Sql Server 2012](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/pull/313).

If there is a feature from Sql Server 2014 that you want support for then create an issue on Github!

EDIT: I installed Sql Server 2014 and tested that it works with the provider set to SqlServer2012. And it does!